# History of Nick carter’s villain Dr Quartz’s creation

Tags: character-analysis, inspiration, nick-carter

What inspired the creation of [Nick Carter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nick_Carter_(literary_character))'s villain [Dr. Quartz](https://pdsh.fandom.com/wiki/Dr._Quartz)? He is described to be an evil vivisectionist so smart that he is versed in every branch of science and usually enjoys cutting women’s flesh. And first appeared in Nick Carter library #13 1891. [This website](http://jessnevins.com/pulp/pulpq/quartz.html) says Frederick Van Rensselaer created him. What is the concept behind his creation?